Is a callback exist when system kill process for activity?
Sometimes system can kill or terminate process of an activity. I need to save data of the activity to shared preferences.
Is any callback will call in this case?
onPause or on onSaveInstanceState not call.

"I need to save data of the activity to shared preferences" -- save the data when the data changes.

@CommonsWare data can changes in 100 places.

That would appear to be an architecture issue.

When the system kills an activity's process, callbacks like onPause(), onStop(), or even onSaveInstanceState() may not always be invoked, particularly in cases of abrupt termination (e.g., low memory). However, to handle such cases and ensure your data is saved to SharedPreferences, you can rely on the ViewModel and lifecycle-aware components like ProcessLifecycleOwner.
